# Have I answered any of a user's questions before?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way to see if I've answered, or commented on, any of a specific user's questions?

Several times I've interacted with a user and want to refer to a specific question of theirs that I've either answered, or commented on. It would be nice to generate a list of those questions (even better if it included answers, I suppose) rather than dig through my own answers/activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

I've written a query for this: [**Interactions with a specific user**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/72826/interactions-with-a-specific-user). It lists both your comments on that user's posts, and answers to their questions, in chronological order.

Only downside is, of course, that the data will not be live, but up to a month old depending on the latest data dump.

Comment: Cool; I'll look at that--I've only played a little with that stuff.

Answer (score 3):

SO answers are meant to be useful to other visitors of the site.

It would be bad if you answered in a way that has a specific meaning for OP and not for everybody. Readers shouldn't have to know your past exchanges to understand the discussion.

So I don't really see this feature as good for SO.

Comment: "Referring to a question" and "creating an answer meaningful only to the asker" are *very* different things.

Comment: Why would you refer to a question specific to OP ? I didn't say "meaningful only to the asker", I say "has a specific meaning" (that is : has more meaning for OP than for rest of SO).

Comment: I've wanted this for several reasons, the most typical being to ease referring back to a previous discussion. I refer to other SO questions in some of my answers regardless of the asker--this is no different, but if I *know* it was related to this asker, this makes it easier, and it would be faster than playing archeologist.

Comment: Then I don't know what you mean by "has a specific meaning for OP". I don't see how anything in the question implies an answer referring to another question of the OP's would be inherently un-useful to anybody else.

Comment: Plus just because *I* want to refer to a previous interaction doesn't mean it would impact the answer in a way demonstrable to someone ignorant of previous exchanges. Plus I'm just curious sometimes.

Comment: Being curious seems to be a valid reason, I agree on this point :)

Comment: Often it's the case that a person will be working on a particular project, and ask a series of questions about that project.  They have one problem, someone provides a solution, and in attempting that solution new problems (and hence new questions) arise.  It can be useful to both look over previous questions for details left out, to see the process as to how the OP got to where they are, etc.  In cases such as these I've also seen the OP not correctly implement a provided answer; seeing the answer they were attempting to solve can be helpful in solving their new problem.